# get image from intent

Tags: android, image, listview

I'm beginner in android, In my project I want to add texts and image from gallery, from add activity and send to main activity to display in a list view,
this is code for add button on main Activity

```
  Intent intentForAdd = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),addActivity.class);
  startActivityForResult(intentForAdd,requestcode2);
```

And this the code for add Activity

```
boolean ownImage = false;
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
byte[] imageDat;
Button buttonAdd,cameraB;
ImageView imageAdd;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    idAdd = findViewById(R.id.idAdd);
    nameAdd = findViewById(R.id.nameAdd);
    cameraB = findViewById(R.id.cameraB);

    buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    imageAdd = findViewById(R.id.imageAdd);
    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int idA = Integer.parseInt(idAdd.getText().toString());
            String nameA = nameAdd.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("NameAdd", nameA);
            intent.putExtra("IdAdd", idA);
            intent.putExtra("ImageAdd",imageData);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
    cameraB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose Image From"),PICK_IMAGE);

        }
    });
}
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED){
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            try{
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap;
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
                imageAdd.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                ownImage = true;
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,byteArrayOutputStream);
                imageData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

This is onActivityResult method in MainActivity to receive the data from add activity and displaay in list view,how to receive the image from add activity ??

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == requestcode2){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String nameAdd = data.getStringExtra("NameAdd");
            int idAdd = data.getIntExtra("IdAdd", 0);
            byte[] img = data.getByteArrayExtra("ImageAdd");
            Employee e = new Employee(idAdd,nameAdd,img);
            list.add(e);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally this is the Employee Class

```
public class Employee {
int id;
String name;
byte[] imgg;
public Employee() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public byte[] getImgg() {
    return imgg;
}

public void setImgg(byte[] imgg) {
    this.imgg = imgg;
}
public Employee(int id, String name, byte[] imgg) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.imgg = imgg;
}
```

The code run correctly when I add texts but the problem in Image did not display in the list

Comment: why dont u just pass the image Uri as a String instead of images byte array?

Answer (score 0):

If your only goal is to save a variable and share it with other activities (you are not doing this to learn how to get an image from an intent) can't you just declare your variable as static?